# subscript out of range, deleting rows with "0" in all cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have an code which is not working now. I use two workbooks, in the first workbook I would like to create an overview list which is getting filled with data from the second workbook.

After the copy paste process many cells are empty or filled with "0". I would like to delete all lines that are filled exclusively with zero or empty. But since I am still a begaenger and can not write a code that deletes the lines if both conditions are true, I filled the empty cells with "0" and now I'm trying to delete all lines that are filled exclusively with "0".

But with the following code I got a

> "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range"

Also the following area is marked yellow: `If sn(j, 4) & sn(j, 5) & sn(j, 6) & sn(j, 7) & sn(j, 8) & sn(j, 9) = "000000" Then`.

```
wb1.Activate
ws1.Select

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'letzte Zeile der Spalte
Set Myrange = Range("D2:AO" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) 'nur Leerzellen
Myrange.Formula = "0"

        sn = Sheets(3).UsedRange

        For j = 1 To UBound(sn)
            If sn(j, 4) & sn(j, 5) & sn(j, 6) & sn(j, 7) & sn(j, 8) & sn(j, 9) = "000000" Then c00 = c00 & "|" & j
        Next

        If c00 <> "" Then
            sn = Application.Index(sn, Application.Transpose(Split(Mid(c00, 2), "|")), [transpose(row(1:8))])
            Sheets(3).UsedRange.ClearContents
            Sheets(3).Cells(1).Resize(UBound(sn), UBound(sn, 2)) = sn
        End If
```

Sheets(3) is also ws1 and after changing Sheets(3) to ws1 I got a "Type mismatch" error and line `sn = Application.Index(sn, Application.Transpose(Split(Mid(c00, 2), "|")), [transpose(row(1:8))])`is marked yellow. Also I'll put a picture of the locals windows screen. [image]

The main task should be to delete the rows which as empty cells or cells which are zero like seeing on the next picture (blue marked line). My first written code was the following but its to slow cause it needs like 5 minutes and sometimes some lines are getting not deleted.

[image]

Best regards,
Bamane

Comment: did you make sure there are `9` columns in the resulting array?  when it stops check the array and make sure it has `9` columns.

Comment: You replace blanks with 0's on `ws1` but then set your `sn` array to `Sheets(3).UsedRange`.   Is `ws1` the same as `Sheets(3)`?  If not, that's likely your problem.  Try changing all instances of `Sheets(3)` with `ws1`, or make sure you copy relevant data from `ws1` to `Sheets(3)`.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes there are more than 9 columns. It starts in column 4 and ends in column 41. In this area I have to check.

Comment: @tigeravatar Sorry for the confusion, ws1 is also sheets(3). When I change sheets(3) into ws1 then I get an other error message: "Type mismatch".

Comment: Not the data on the sheet.  when it stops did you go to the locals window and check the actual array, to verify that the data was being loaded properly? I doubt that `lBound(sn,2) = 4`

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes I checked it and I put a screenshot into my question. There you can see that sn has 9582 entires and my data has after deleting duplicates only 2958 lines. After that all sn are empty. Can you say me if that is the problem and how I can solve this?

Comment: So it was the sheet that @tigeravatar stated, because now you are getting the error in a different place.  I think you will need to loop the split array and load a separate array, instead of INDEX.  Also the first item in the split array will be blank as your string starts with the delimiter.

Comment: @ScottCraner To be honest, I am still an amateur what vba concerns and I can not quite understand that. I have read in the field arrays but  for this case I need more practice experience to solve it. 
It would be great if you could include  the index in the code and an explanation would be great.

Comment: @Bamane I think you need to re-approach the situation here - there is definitely an easier way to write this. Are you just trying to delete rows where D through I are zeroes?

Comment: @dwirony I added an update on my question there you can see how the data looks like after being copied into sheets(3).

Comment: Is column AP used?

Comment: @GMalc The column AP is not used. AO is tha last used column.

Comment: Then see my answer, based on dwirony suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Like dwirony said you need to re-approach how you are trying to accomplish this.  Since I don't know what type of data you have in every column this is the best example I can provide you. You don't need to insert "0"s into the empty cells. Your best bet is to use a helper column(AP if it is empty) to sum the data in every row starting from D2 to AO2. Add a Filter for "0" in Column AP and then delete all Visible cells. You may have to modify the code below to meet any requirements not identified in your question.

```
Dim LR As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("AP2:AP" & LR).Formula = "=SUM(D2:AO2)"
    .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=42, Criteria1:="0"
    .Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the code also this is a great idea. 
I got a "Run-time error 1004: AutoFilter method of Range class failed". 
Then the following line is marked in yellow: `.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=42, Criteria1:="0"`

Comment: Will get back with you, i have to run off right now

Comment: thank you very much for the update. I think its working now, but the "rowscout" is not working correctly cause there are also some lines in column 3 that are free. I tried this code `ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    lastrow3 = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1` but its also not working. Do you know an other option for this?

Comment: @Bamane, your "rowscout" is not "Rows.Count", What do you mean "some lines in column 3 are free"? You have to use a column that has a value in the last used row, If column 3 does not have a value in the last row, then use a column that does have a value in the last row, most people use column 1.

Comment: Hi, I mean "Rows.Count". I thought if there are empty cells in the middle of the column then the last column will be in the middle. Like when you press Ctrl+Alt+down arrow.

Comment: When you use `End(xlUp)` it will identify the last used cell in column 3 from the bottom. `End(xlDown)` will stop at the first empty cell in column 3

Comment: @GMaIc I see. I tried a lot but there is still the error message _Run-time error 1004: AutoFilter method of Range class failed_ . In column 42 (AP) the sum is in every line also there are lots of Null as General format. But it is not deleting the rows. Maybe this code is working for a smaller range...what do you think?